# Let E/F be a finite extension of infinite fields. Prove that the index of (F, +) in (E, +) is finite if and only if E = F.

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I know that if E/F is a finite field extension then E is an algebraic

extension over F. But I don't quite know what to do from there. Any

suggestions will help. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Consider $a\in E$ with $a\notin F$, and consider $\lambda a$
for $\lambda\in F$. Are these all distinct in the quotient group $E/F$?

Comment: Thank you. But how can I use that to show that [E:F]=1?

Comment: The the index $[E:F]$ is the same as the order of the quotient group $E/F$.